# LLVM/clang outputting to MIPS, but not working in SPIM

Tags: clang, llvm, mips, simulator, spim

Given the file

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
      printf("hello world\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I can use the commands

```
clang -emit-llvm hello.c -c -o hello.bc
llc hello.bc -march=mipsel -relocation-model=static -o hello.s
```

to produce a nice bit of what looks like MIPS code, (placed below, to avoid breaking up the text) unfortunately, when I try and run it in my trusty SPIM simulator for MIPS I find that SPIM objects to almost every line of it.  Not only the '.Section .mdebug.abi32' lines but also 
any line of the form '.cfi*' - and even more confusingly (because it looks like MIPS to me...) the line 'lui    $2, %hi(__gnu_local_gp)" is objected to.

I am looking for some information on the different flavours of MIPS that SPIM and LLVM cope with, *or* someone to give an example of a MIPS simulator I can run that accepts the MIPS code that LLVM is producing.

```
    .Section .mdebug.abi32
    .previous
    .file   "hello.bc"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .align  2
    .type   main,@function
    .set    nomips16                # @main
    .ent    main
main:
    .cfi_startproc
    .frame  $sp,32,$ra
    .mask   0x80000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    addiu   $sp, $sp, -32
$tmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    sw  $ra, 28($sp)            # 4-byte Folded Spill
$tmp3:
    .cfi_offset 31, -4
    lui $2, %hi(__gnu_local_gp)
    addiu   $2, $2, %lo(__gnu_local_gp)
    sw  $2, 16($sp)
    sw  $zero, 24($sp)
    lui $2, %hi($.str)
    addiu   $4, $2, %lo($.str)
    jal printf
    nop
    addiu   $2, $zero, 0
    lw  $ra, 28($sp)            # 4-byte Folded Reload
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 32
    jr  $ra
    nop
    .set    macro
    .set    reorder
    .end    main
$tmp4:
    .size   main, ($tmp4)-main
    .cfi_endproc

    .type   $.str,@object           # @.str
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
$.str:
    .asciz   "hello world\n"
    .size   $.str, 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Spim is a simple teaching tool which does not support gnu assembler. You might try using [OVPsim](http://www.ovpworld.org/gettingstarted), which has complete models of various real MIPS processors. You can run Linux on OVPsim, and you should be able to run a MIPS Linux executable produced by clang on that simulated Linux.

Comment: Another route, if you are running Linux, would be to use the QEMU Linux user mode emulator for Mips. That's what I use for my clang based ELLCC tool chain. (http://ellcc.org)

Answer (score 0):

The Mips assembly printer in LLVM emits assembly in GAS format (suitable for consumption by the GNU assembler and compatible tools). There's a very good chance SPIM cannot read that. However, if SPIM could read Mips binaries, you could try to emit an object file from LLVM and let SPIM handle that.

Binaries are more "universal" since they must be understood by the CPU itself. Alas, each assembler usually has its own specific syntax only it understands, and assemblers don't tend to be compatible with each other and disagree on basic things like operator ordering, punctuation semantics, directives, and so on.